# How to combine 4 JS with one variable in common

Tags: javascript

I have 4 pages in 4 different languages (en, fr, de, it) and for each of them I'm using a different JS to print the correct month.

```
function getDate(){var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
var today = new Date(); var dd = today.getDate(); var mm = today.getMonth(); var minutes = today.getMinutes();
if (minutes < 10)  minutes = '0'+minutes; var hour = today.getHours(); var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
if(dd<10){dd='0'+dd} var today = dd+'  '+ monthNames[mm]+'  '+yyyy+' - '+hour+':'+minutes; return today;}

function getDate(){var monthNames = ["Janvier", "Février", "Mars", "Avril", "Mai", "Juin", "Juillet", "Août", "Septembre", "Octobre", "Novembre", "Décembre"];
var today = new Date(); var dd = today.getDate(); var mm = today.getMonth(); var minutes = today.getMinutes();
if (minutes < 10)  minutes = '0'+minutes; var hour = today.getHours(); var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
if(dd<10){dd='0'+dd} var today = dd+'  '+ monthNames[mm]+'  '+yyyy+' - '+hour+':'+minutes; return today;}

function getDate(){var monthNames = ["Januar", "Februar", "März", "April", "Mai", "Juni", "Juli", "August", "September", "Oktober", "November", "Dezember"];
var today = new Date(); var dd = today.getDate(); var mm = today.getMonth(); var minutes = today.getMinutes();
if (minutes < 10)  minutes = '0'+minutes; var hour = today.getHours(); var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
if(dd<10){dd='0'+dd} var today = dd+'  '+ monthNames[mm]+'  '+yyyy+' - '+hour+':'+minutes; return today;}

function getDate(){var monthNames = ["Gennaio", "Febbraio", "Marzo", "Aprile", "Maggio", "Giugno", "Luglio", "Agosto", "Settembre", "Ottobre", "Novembre", "Dicembre"];
var today = new Date(); var dd = today.getDate(); var mm = today.getMonth(); var minutes = today.getMinutes();
if (minutes < 10)  minutes = '0'+minutes; var hour = today.getHours(); var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
if(dd<10){dd='0'+dd} var today = dd+'  '+ monthNames[mm]+'  '+yyyy+' - '+hour+':'+minutes; return today;}
```

Then I call it in the text simply with this:

```
<script>document.write(getDate());</script>
```

Now I would like to get rid of those 4 different pages and use variables to display in 1 page only the correct month, basing on visitors' browser language.

How can I combine the 4 scripts in order to display the month in a specific language basing on visitor? (the 4 scripts are identical, the only difference is the month names)

I'm trying with the following attempt, but without success, since my JS knowledge is not good enough yet. Can anybody please help me into this?

```
function getDate(){
var monthNames = 
  let phrase;
  if (italian) {phrase = phrases.italian; }
  else if (french) {phrase = phrases.french; }
  else if (german) {phrase = phrases.german; }
  else {phrase = phrases.english; }
  el.innerHTML = `${phrase}`;  };
  modifyElHTML('comentario', {
italian: ("Gennaio", "Febbraio", "Marzo", "Aprile", "Maggio", "Giugno", "Luglio", "Agosto", "Settembre", "Ottobre", "Novembre", "Dicembre"]);
french: ("Janvier", "Février", "Mars", "Avril", "Mai", "Juin", "Juillet", "Août", "Septembre", "Octobre", "Novembre", "Décembre"]);
german: ("Januar", "Februar", "März", "April", "Mai", "Juni", "Juli", "August", "September", "Oktober", "November", "Dezember"]);
english: ("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]);
var today = new Date(); var dd = today.getDate(); var mm = today.getMonth(); var minutes = today.getMinutes();
if (minutes < 10)  minutes = '0'+minutes; var hour = today.getHours(); var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
if(dd<10){dd='0'+dd} var today = dd+'  '+ monthNames[mm]+'  '+yyyy+' - '+hour+':'+minutes; return today;}
```

Comment: Why not consider using the [Intl Web API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat)?

Comment: Definitely go for a library. I'm using Luxon, and I live happy: https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/

Comment: Both ideas look good but I have no competences to set them up as variables, that's why I was trying to recycle my code...

Comment: You just need to refactor your code: The List of month names should be a parameter to the `getDate()` function. So the `getDate(listOfMonthNames)` function would simply be called with different list of months like: `var iatlianMonths = [...]; var result = getDate(italianMonths);`.

Now you only need to find a way how to decide, when to call the function with which list of month names.

Comment: @SvenEppler can you be more conchrete maybe typing a reply to this post? Sorry newbie here. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Just extract the list of month names from the `getDate` function:

```js
// Store all the different month names in a javascript object
// so the language is the key and the month names are the values
const monthNames = {
   german: ["Januar", "Februar", "März", "April", "Mai", "Juni", "Juli", "August", "September", "Oktober", "November", "Dezember"],
   italian: ["Gennaio", "Febbraio", "Marzo", "Aprile", "Maggio", "Giugno", "Luglio", "Agosto", "Settembre", "Ottobre", "Novembre", "Dicembre"],
   english: [],
   french: []
};

// Somehow retrieve the userLanguage (needs to be implemented by you)
const userLanguage = getUserLanguage();

// Check if we can find the list of month names for the given userLanguage
// If we can't find a matching monthName list, we throw an Error
if(monthNames[userLange] === undefined) {
    throw new Error(`No monthNames for userLanguage='${userLanguage} found!`);
}
// If we could find a matching monthName list, we just use it to call getDate(monthNames)
else {
    // Retrieve the list inside the monthNames object
    const actualMonthNames = monthNames[userLanguage];
    // Call getDate with the extracted list of monthNames
    const dateResult = getDate(actualMonthNames);

    console.log(`dateResult=${dateResult}`);
}

// Your original function, which now accepts a list of monthNames as parameter.
function getDate(monthNames) {
    var today = new Date(); var dd = today.getDate(); var mm = today.getMonth(); var minutes = today.getMinutes();
    if (minutes < 10)  minutes = '0'+minutes; var hour = today.getHours(); var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    if(dd<10){dd='0'+dd} var today = dd+'  '+ monthNames[mm]+'  '+yyyy+' - '+hour+':'+minutes; return today;
}
```

That's how an implementation could look like. You still need to implement the `getUserLanguage()` function. Which should return a string like "german" or "italian". The important thing is, that this string matches a key in the object `monthNames`.